# How to resolve an id by an foreign table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to resolve an ID by another table, where the name of this id is stored.

```
SELECT d.id_data, string_agg(s.name_last,', ') AS authors, d.title, i.name
FROM data d, institution i, staffs s
WHERE d.id_staffs = s.id_staffs 
    AND d.id_institution = i.id_institution 
GROUP BY d.id_data limit 100 ;
```

But how can I get the name of my Institution. I want that the SELECT shows me the institution name, which has stored the data. Something like that

```
id_data | authors               | title    | name
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       |Mustermann, Musterfrau | sunmaker | university cologne
2       |Schmidt, Müller        | dry age  | university berlin
```

I just need to resolve the id of the institution to his name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.**  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT d.id_data, string_agg(s.name_last,', ') AS authors,
       d.title, i.name
FROM data d JOIN
     institution i
     ON d.id_staffs = s.id_staffs JOIN
     staffs s
     ON d.id_institution = i.id_institution 
GROUP BY d.id_data, d.title, i.name 
LIMIT 100 ;
```

That is, fix the `GROUP BY` to have all the unaggregated columns.